# Protractor Version 2.0.0

Tags: protractor-net

before, i was using protractor version 1.5.0 and now i am updated with protractor 2.0.0 and the code that works in 1.5.0 is not working in 2.0.0, 
anyone please help me to sort out this.

let me show you my code that i wrote in 1.5.0:

```
var path = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('/xpathforelement/'));
browser.actions().mouseDown(path).perform();
```

Now, same is not working in 2.0.0.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? What did you try to make it work?

Comment: yes,it is showing an error, UnknownError: null,   even i tried mouseMove() , mouseUp() evenets , but showing same error.  is it so that mouse events are not supporting in this newer version